# HQL currentdate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to create queries in HQL using the `currentdate()` function to compare two dates.

```
List<Rel_Utenti_Commesse> commesseAttive = new ArrayList<Rel_Utenti_Commesse>();        

commesseAttive = session.createQuery("from Rel_Utenti_Commesse where utenti = '" + utenteSessione + "' and data_fine_commessa > current_date() or data_fine_commessa is null").list();

for(int i = 0; i < commesseAttive.size(); i++)                   
    System.out.println(commesseAttive.get(i).getCommessa().getNome_commessa());

return commesseAttive;
```

But although I have in the database (MySQL) an instance with a data_fine_commessa with 2019-02-01, he ignores it.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the braces arrond the or part:

```
commesseAttive = session.createQuery("from Rel_Utenti_Commesse where utenti = '" + utenteSessione + "' and (data_fine_commessa > current_date() or data_fine_commessa is null)").list();
```

That's why first is `AND` evaluated and than the `OR`

@TimBiegeleisen suggested, use parametrized queries:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Rel_Utenti_Commesse where utenti = :utenteSessione and (data_fine_commessa > current_date() or data_fine_commessa is null)")
query.setParameter("utenteSessione", utenteSessione)
List result = query.list()
```

Comment: Don't know if it's possible with HQL, but a prepared statement might be helpful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why braces should not be possible in HQL?

Comment: No, I'm not referring to that.  I was referring to that the HQL query string is being built with concatenation.  This would be bad with ordinary SQL...not sure about HQL.  +1 to you anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah ok. Sorry for my missunderstanding. Yes it is possible to use placeholder in HQL